# display date format

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display 2-March-2011 is like  '02-March-2011'.

Comment: The question is very clear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just replace the hardcoded date with your value

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2-March-2011');
$newDate = date('d-F-Y', $timestamp); 
echo $newDate; //outputs 02-March-2011
```

Answer (score 20):

```
<?php
    // Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
    // Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

    $today = date("j-F-Y");                          // 10-March-2001
    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
    $today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
    $today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
    $today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
    $today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
    $today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
    $today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
    $today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
    $today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
    ?>
```

Refer this link also....

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: i am using this echo date('g:i:s',strtotime($total_time)); but it shows hours 12 if hours are 0 if hours are grater than zero then it shows correct

Answer (score 5):

You could use regex, string splitting, `sprintf()`, etc, but I'd rather use the native DateTime object.

```
$str = '2-March-2011';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-F-Y', $str);

var_dump($date->format('d-F-Y')); // string(13) "02-March-2011"
```

[See it](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wnma9Z).

Answer (score 4):

Convert the input string to a timestamp, then format that as desired. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for formatting options.

```
$input = '2-March-2011';
$time = strtotime($input);
$output = date('d-F-Y',$time);
```

Short version:

```
echo date('d-F-Y',strtotime('2-March-2011'));
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick hop over to [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) reveals that everyone else was correct when they said this:

```
echo date('d-F-Y', strtotime('2-March-2011'));
```

Comment: Actually, that would print 02-Mar-2011. Needs to be d-F-Y

Comment: Correct. Force of habit for me to seek out the three-letter one. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the date as a Unix timestamp (eg: `$date = time();`), then you can just use the inbuilt `date()` function:

```
echo date('j-F-Y');
```

Otherwise, you can look at using `strtotime()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get it into Unix time, or alternatively use a more object-oriented approach as **alex** has shown.

Answer (score 0):

Code Sample : echo date('d-F-Y',strtotime('2011-03-02'));

you can format you date in many ways
here you can find all the formats [date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)