# how to get actual date in DD-MMM-YY format in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to store the actual sysdate using php in DD-MMM-YY format. I want to use that date to run an insert in an oracle sql server.

thanks

Comment: PHP [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Comment: please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. To ask a perfect question also read how to create [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But your question is fairly simple, so I suggest to go read some more tutorials, to many out there to suggest any. Try google with search string `current date DD-MMM-YY format  PHP`

Comment: 7 downvotes in 11 mins? new SO record?

Answer (score 6):

try the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
date('d-M-y');
```

this will return the date in this format: 15-Dec-15 (today).

Comment: @davejal edited, thanks.

Comment: @user3636110 see the edit

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty simple. You must google anything before posting.
Here is complete list:

```
<?php
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

$today = date("j-F-Y");                          // 10-March-2001
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
?>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074531/display-date-format)

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
date('d-m-Y');
```

If you want more examples: http://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-dates-and-times/

Answer (score 2):

to have Jan, Feb (MMM) and two digit year use:

```
date("d-M-y");
```